# Designing a paper plane for the game

Tags: adobe-photoshop, games

I need to draw a paper plane for my game. I have pretty much PS experience but still have  problems with easy tasks. It must be totally 2d , so most examples that can be found on the internet are inappropriate. And all my own works look primitively(at best).

- Any advices or examples?

Comment: (I would use AI, but that is not the question.) Do you want something flat like this? http://djiqd110ru30i.cloudfront.net/upload/381424/pattern/53372/full_3366_53372_PaperPlanePaperPiecedPattern_1.jpg

Comment: yes, mostly. but in my game 2d paper plane flyies from left side to the right side, from the bottom  and other way, so I must  make different paper planes for every angle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**These steps will work the same in either Illustrator or Photoshop**

*Illustrator may be easier for what you need but if you want to use Photoshop you can still follow these steps:*

Why don't you actually make a paper plane and take a photo of it from what ever angle you need e.g. from the top or from the side and then import the image into Photoshop.

Then create a new layer and use the pen tool to draw paths over the plane until it looks like the one you made and then fill in the path shapes to create your "plane".

All you have to do then is remove the layer with the photo of the plane on and you're left with the image you drew.

Just save that image with a transparent background and implement it into your game how you see fit.

Comment: just can't found a good link to download Illustrator for Mac

Comment: @Vinand Can't find a good link? it's not a free program. You can download a trial from http://www.adobe.com/go/tryillustrator/

Comment: @Vinand - if you're interested in a Mac-only vector program that's cheaper than Illustrator, give Sketch a try...I haven't personally used it but it's gotten good reviews. Inkscape is the most well-known open-source alternative for vector drawing, but I find it hard to use.

Comment: If I decide to buy a vector editor in the future,I will better pay for Illustrator.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the same steps as outlined would work pretty much the same way in Photoshop. Perhaps add that to your answer?

Comment: @AlanGilbertson I've added what you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/en/), with the following steps:

1. Get the base drawing (draw yourself, or "Trace Bitmap" and modify).
2. To get additional "views" of the drawing use the arrows to strech/skew/flip the image. Use the "Perspective" filter (Extensions->Modify Path->Perspective) for advanced control of the output.

See also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpOawwLt6cc).

Comment: and [this](http://www.built-to-spec.com/blog/2011/01/02/quick-inkscape-tutorial-perspective-transforms/)